# Altering Skeleton framework to 1400px as default

Tags: css, html, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm quite new to skeleton but I would like to use it for a project. The project consists of 4 divs that have a maximum width of 1400px, and I would need these to scale down along with the browser. I'm not sure how I would go about altering the standard sixteen column width of 960px to 1400px and the various media queries associated with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

If anybody is interested in this, Ian Yates does a good job explaining it in this article/tutorial series:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/building-a-responsive-layout-with-skeleton-widescreen/

It is simply a case of setting your desired min-width media query into skeleton.css and changing the values; either percentage of pixel-based. Here is mine as an example.

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 1400px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
    .container                                  { width: 1400px; } /*whatever you want - can even be fixed if you prefer*/
    .container .column,
    .container .columns                         { margin-left: 0.78125%; margin-right: 0.78125%;  }
    .container .one.column,
    .container .one.columns                     { width: 4.6875%; }
    .container .two.columns                     { width: 10.9375%; }
    .container .three.columns                   { width: 17.1875%; }
    .container .four.columns                    { width: 23.4375%; }
    .container .five.columns                    { width: 29.6875%; }
    .container .six.columns                     { width: 35.9375%; }
    .container .seven.columns                   { width: 42.1875%; }
    .container .eight.columns                   { width: 48.4375%; }
    .container .nine.columns                    { width: 54.6875%; }
    .container .ten.columns                     { width: 60.9375%; }
    .container .eleven.columns                  { width: 67.1875%; }
    .container .twelve.columns                  { width: 73.4375%; }
    .container .thirteen.columns                { width: 79.6875%; }
    .container .fourteen.columns                { width: 85.9375%; }
    .container .fifteen.columns                 { width: 92.1875%; }
    .container .sixteen.columns                 { width: 98.4375%; }
    .container .one-third.column                { width: 31.7708%; }
    .container .two-thirds.column               { width: 65.1041%; }
    /* Offsets */
    .container .offset-by-one                   { padding-left: 6.25%; }
    .container .offset-by-two                   { padding-left: 12.5%; }
    .container .offset-by-three                 { padding-left: 18.75%; }
    .container .offset-by-four                  { padding-left: 25%; }
    .container .offset-by-five                  { padding-left: 31.25%; }
    .container .offset-by-six                   { padding-left: 37.5%; }
    .container .offset-by-seven                 { padding-left: 43.75%; }
    .container .offset-by-eight                 { padding-left: 50%; }
    .container .offset-by-nine                  { padding-left: 56.25%; }
    .container .offset-by-ten                   { padding-left: 62.5%; }
    .container .offset-by-eleven                { padding-left: 68.75%; }
    .container .offset-by-twelve                { padding-left: 75%; }
    .container .offset-by-thirteen              { padding-left: 81.25%; }
    .container .offset-by-fourteen              { padding-left: 87.5%; }
    .container .offset-by-fifteen               { padding-left: 93.75%; }
}
```